# `window.open` on the second monitor in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, popup, window.open

When I'm using firefox and then using `window.open('blah.com','blah','left=-30,top=-300');`, the popup opens in my second display above my first one but in chrome, the popup just opens at `left=0,top=0`. Is there a reason why chrome is doing this and how would I fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps chrome doesn't let you open windows outside the viewport?

Answer (score 25):

This is a bug in Chrome when the pop-up window is opened on the secondary monitor. The Chrome folks seem to say that this is a security issue (though how this is a security issue is beyond me).

Now, opening a pop-up window on a NON-EXISTENT secondary monitor, I could understand is a security issue, but... whatever.

Here's a link to a discussion on the matter:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137681

Comment: Yes, I only see this issue on an extended monitor

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue discussion.  I don't see Chrome folks talking about security... For the most part, they haven't said anything :(

Comment: My issue was that I wanted to open new windows only on 2nd monitor, darn thing wouldnt budge past the first mon. Works beautifully in FF, though it also opens same URL in main window also...thats weird. Damn opinionated folks at Google ! Ok I take that back, FF doesn't even have the option to open all bookmarks in a folder, leave alone in tabs or new window (ref. https://superuser.com/questions/220708/chrome-bookmarks-in-folder-open-all-in-new-windows)

Comment: I suppose one could find out how many screens a user has and on which chrome is positioned, which could be used to fingerprint the user.

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old post but here's my solution to it. Just use the "avail*" properties of the screen object:

```
var windowSize = {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
};
var windowLocation = {
    left:  (window.screen.availLeft + (window.screen.availWidth / 2)) - (windowSize.width / 2),
    top: (window.screen.availTop + (window.screen.availHeight / 2)) - (windowSize.height / 2)
};
window.open(http://example.com, '_blank', 'width=' + windowSize.width + ', height=' + windowSize.height + ', left=' + windowLocation.left + ', top=' + windowLocation.top);
```

Basically, the "window.screen.availLeft" gives you the other screens width so you can add you're normal center calculation to that.

Answer (score 11):

```
var w = 300;
var h = 300;
var left = (window.screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (window.screen.height/2)-(h/2);

var win = window.open("example.html", "_blank", 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h);
win.moveTo(left, top);
```

for **Chrome**...

Comment: Despite the up-votes, this doesn't work. Maybe it worked in 2013, but doesn't work in 2022. The window remains constrained to the same window as the parent window.
Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this StackOverflow's post [Center a popup window on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen/13623158)

I've made a little upgrade for that function a couple of years ago.

```
function multipleScreenPopup(url, title, w, h, centered = true, moveRight = 0, moveDown = 0, resizable = "no") {
  // Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox
  var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
  var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

  var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
  var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

  var left = 0;
  var top = 0;
  if (centered === true) {
    left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
    top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
  } else {
    left = dualScreenLeft + moveRight;
    top = dualScreenTop + moveDown;
  }

  var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=' + resizable + ', width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

  // Puts focus on the newWindow
  if (window.focus) {
    newWindow.focus();
    }

}

// centered as of the monitor that fired on it
multipleScreenPopup('https://google.com', '_blank', 500, 500);

// move from the left and from the top
multipleScreenPopup('https://yahoo.com', '_blank', 500, 500, false, 200, 200);
```

Comment: In my testing on Windows 10, this works fine on a PRIMARY monitor. However, on a SECONDARY monitor this works great on Opera, unreliably on Firefox and not at all on Chrome/Edge.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I've had similar problems:

```
var w = 300;
var h = 300;
var left = (window.screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (window.screen.height/2)-(h/2);

var win = window.open("example.html", "_blank", 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
```

--centers the popup window in Firefox but **not in Chrome**. Also, notice, this is not outside the display area...

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm looking into Chrome being ... odd, now in 2018. From what I can tell chrome ignores all of the "specs" in the third argument if ANY of them are not supported. I have found no way to be able to check for this functionality at a code level in order to implement a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works, though method is experimental and may not function in the future

```
 var screenDetails = await window.getScreenDetails()
 if (screen.isExtended && screenDetails.screens.length > 1) {
  var newWindow = window.open(
     "https://ya.ru",
     "New Window",
    `popup,width=${myWidth},height=${myHeight},left=0,top=0`
  );
  newWindow.moveTo(screenDetails.screens[1].left + myMargin, 0);
 }
```