# window.open, chrome brings window back to invoking window screen in dual screen setup

Tags: javascript, html

Chrome behaves differently than IE and FF when opening a window with API `window.open` and left position specified to a position on the right screen/monitor in a dual screen setup ([screen1][screen2]).

The same happens when the invoking screen is on the right monitor, the left position always starts in the second monitor, although after opening the property `screenX` correctly reports the screen width and not 0 (put this window in the second monitor and set `left=0` in the jsfiddle below to test this).

It seems that Chrome always snaps the popup position to the invoking window screen.

- Chrome 41.0.2272.76 m
- FF 36.0.1
- IE 11.0.9600.17633

You can try it out in this tiny fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/inglun/en59odar/

For sure, it is an adjustment to prevent windows to end up off screen that fails to take second screen into account. Bug? Is there a way around this?

*In the real use case, users place a window on the second screen expecting it to end up there during the following session (maybe tomorrow). Positions are saved in local storage.*

Answer (score 0):

I found this with some searching and modified it per your example ...

```
$(function()
{
    $('#btnOpen').click(function(){
    // change 2100 put window on right screen
    var windowSize = {
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
    };
    var windowLocation = {
        left:  (window.screen.availLeft + (window.screen.availWidth / 2)) - (windowSize.width / 2),
        top: (window.screen.availTop + (window.screen.availHeight / 2)) - (windowSize.height / 2)
    };

    window.open('about:blank', null, 'width=' + windowSize.width + ', height=' + windowSize.height + ', left=' + windowLocation.left + ', top=' + windowLocation.top)

    });
});
```

source is: [popup open position in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754260/popup-open-position-in-chrome/17972796#17972796)