# How can I open a browser window in a dual monitor setup on a specific monitor?

Tags: javascript, windows, popup, popupwindow, multiple-monitors

I am trying to create a JS function that opens a pop-up browser window on a user's second monitor only when they are in the extend screen when they load the website using:

```
window.onload = window.open(link);
```

This will be used in very specific scenarios as it is in a company computer that all have the same settings.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated on how to guide me on this.

Comment: @connexo That's your opinion.  I can think of *several* application-specific reasons to open windows on other monitors that I've hit in the past, where instead the user has had to open the window, drag it over to the other, and then fullscreen it in 3 distinct steps.  Consider for a moment that not every site has the same requirements.

Comment: @kun0 See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24680628/362536

Comment: @Brad Thank you for the link. I will try it out and then tell you how it goes!

Comment: @connexo Of course the user should be in control.  If the user wants to use a web application that outputs to a second monitor, they should be able to easily do that.  Unfortunately, closed-minded folks such as yourself make assumptions about what users want to do with their browsers, limiting capability and usability.  This isn't a hard problem to solve... we already have a nice Permissions API, and plenty of precedent for other functionality.  Perhaps if fewer developers were blindly opposed to user-beneficial features, we could get on with improving apps... for the sake of users.