# window.open to center of screen

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, window.open

I am using window.open to open a popup window like so:

`<a href="http://path/to/url" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'sharegplus', 'height=485,width=700'); return false;" target="_blank">`

I want this to be centered in the screen, but without having to use `<script> inline code </script>` and merely enter whatever I need within `onclick=""`. Can this be done?

Comment: @Rionmonster The accepted answer to that question is a pretty terrible script, and not even complete.

Comment: @Pointy, perhaps you could improve upon it and post.  Or, at least give some guidance to Alex about what makes it terrible.

Comment: Why do you want it only in the `onclick`? That's going to get very unreadable, very fast.

Comment: unless you can make the best alternative. it must be able to be used multiple times in one page, but the width, height and position will always stay the same

Comment: One of reasons of using inline event `onclick` is to pass over popup blockers. According to many SO answers only inline JS can open new window without activating popup blocker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center a popup window on screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen)

Comment: Check This [Window in center screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen)

Answer (score 32):

#### Edit

This is a bad answer.  a much better answer can be found here:
[window.open() on a multi-monitor/dual-monitor system - where does window pop up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363474/window-open-on-a-multi-monitor-dual-monitor-system-where-does-window-pop-up)

But in the meantime while i decide when i want to update this answer, this fiddle accounts for dual monitor setups: http://jsfiddle.net/w665x/138/

#### Original Answer

This might work for you.  Not confident in it being entirely cross-browser, but close;

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function goclicky(meh)
{
    var x = screen.width/2 - 700/2;
    var y = screen.height/2 - 450/2;
    window.open(meh.href, 'sharegplus','height=485,width=700,left='+x+',top='+y);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://path/to/url" onclick="goclicky(this); return false;" target="_blank">blah</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/w665x/)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try:

```
$('a.popup-window').on('click', function(){
    var w = 880, h = 600,
        left = Number((screen.width/2)-(w/2)), tops = Number((screen.height/2)-(h/2)),
        popupWindow = window.open(this.href, '', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=1, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+tops+', left='+left);
    popupWindow.focus(); return false;
});
```

And call:

```
<a href="https://google.com/" class="popup-window">Open in new window</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly:

```
//Code Starts
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#Popup').click(function() {
     var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'height=800,width=800');
     if (window.focus) 
     {
       NWin.focus();
     }
     return false;
    });
});​
//Code Ends


<a href="http://www.google.com/" id="Popup">Open in Popup window</a>
```

Comment: Source: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/open-link-in-new-tab-or-new-popup.html

Comment: Can you provide some explanation of how it works, beyond including the link?

Answer (score 0):

This code uses **jAplus** script. It allows you to do this without writing JavaScript code. (http://japlus.simplit.it)

```
<head>
   <script src="/path/to/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script src="/path/to/jquery.Aplus.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://path/to/url" class="win win-center">
</body>
</html>
```