# How to show a webpage onto another monitor connected to it on click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where you enter customer details and on click of a submit button which generates a PDF. This PDF tab should be visible on both the  monitors(Dual screen). 
In the second monitor the user goes through the PDF and sign's on it.

[window.open() on a multi-monitor/dual-monitor system - where does window pop up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363474/window-open-on-a-multi-monitor-dual-monitor-system-where-does-window-pop-up)

I tried the above link but didn't work

Comment: Browser has to be Internet Explorer, thank you

Comment: What did happen when you tried the advice from the link?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: FindLeftScreenBoundry is not defined"

Comment: Okay... Let me tell you what I am trying to do. I will enter customer details into a webpage and on the click of a button we will generate a PDF with the customer details in it, now I want the PDF to be visible in the second monitor for the customer to check and confirm the details are correct and he will sign on the PDF using a signature pad. Once the signature is done, On click of a button in primary monitor the tab in the second monitor should be closed.

Comment: The solution at the link you posted shows a `function FindLeftScreenBoundry()` being declared. If you are getting an error that this function is not declared, you simply did not implement the function properly. It does not mean that that solution doesn't work.

Comment: Oops.. I didn't declare the function.. thank you.. but the "leftScreenBoundary" is coming undefined.

Comment: Looks like the OP just made a typo following advice from another post. i will close this question and mark as a duplicate.

Comment: There is a answer by now see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57303963/1497139