# window.open() to another screen (second display)

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have this line of JavaScript code:

```
window.open('queue.html', 'QueueMonitor', 'toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=' + screen.availWidth);
```

The expected output is to open a popup on the second display monitor - this works fine in Firefox and IE11 but not in Chrome, Opera and Edge. I've already tried looking for similar problems, but I can't find a solution.

Do you have any idea why? or how to go about this?

**EDIT 1**

I'm sorry, I didn't put there that *but not in....* means, the popup is displayed in the main display monitor and not in the second.

**EDIT 2**

Tried adding `width=100,height=100`, but it only gives me this (on the said 3 browsers):
[image: Popup screenshot]
You can see it's like in between the 2 screens - not really in half but there's some window boundary left on the main display (left).

Comment: I think these browsers don't support some specs of `window.open()`.

Comment: It might get blocked in that browsers. Popup blockers usually works blocking every popup, which is not triggered by a direct user action, like clicking on a button or a link.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a width and height like this:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com/', 'name', 'width=400,height=320,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=' + screen.availWidth);
```

I tested this in the developer console in Google Chrome (Version 60.0.3112.113).

---

### Edit

As this question is specifically related to displaying the new window on the second display the above answer won't suffice. As mentioned in my comment I recommend checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363474/window-open-on-a-multi-monitor-dual-monitor-system-where-does-window-pop-up) as it might help you.

Comment: Already tried putting width and height, it doesn't go to the second display. I'm using version 71.0.3578.98

Comment: Wait. Is the issue it not being displayed on the second monitor or there being no popout at all?

Comment: Sorry, the issue is it not being displayed on the second monitor. Had to put an edit to my question.

Comment: I suggest reading up on this post, it probably covers what you need.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363474/window-open-on-a-multi-monitor-dual-monitor-system-where-does-window-pop-up

Answer (score 0):

Could you check below for specs parameter of window.open and let us know whether this helps you:

- resizable:   IE only
- scrollbars:  IE, Firefox & Opera only
- toolbar:     IE and Firefox only

Comment: Do these parameters have to do with `left` not working on other browsers?

Comment: @dunli Could you check the value of screen.availWidth when opening in Chrome. It should not be negative.