# Open a screen popup in second screen using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, window.open

I want to open my application page on the second screen using Javascript. I got an example from one of the answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363474/window-open-on-a-multi-monitor-dual-monitor-system-where-does-window-pop-up). The example works well, if I have my parent application on the right screen, it opens the window on left. But it does not work if my parent screen is on left screen.

What I want is, I want to open the window on other screen to my parent page screen. This is how the example looks like.

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h, opts) {
       var _innerOpts = '';
       if(opts !== null && typeof opts === 'object' ){
           for (var p in opts ) {
               if (opts.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                   _innerOpts += p + '=' + opts[p] + ',';
               }
           }
       }

       // Fixes dual-screen position, Most browsers, Firefox
       var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
       var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

       console.log('dualScreenLeft' + dualScreenLeft); 
       console.log('dualScreenTop' + dualScreenTop); 

       var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
       var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

       console.log('wigth' + width); 
       console.log('height' + height); 

       var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
       var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;

       console.log('calculated left ' + left); 
       console.log('calcualted top ' + top); 


       var newWindow = window.open(url, title, _innerOpts + ' width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

    // Puts focus on the newWindow
       if (window.focus) {
           newWindow.focus();
       }
    };
```

What I should change in my code so it automatically detects the screen and opens the window on another screen.

I am trying this on Firefox and IE (11).

Comment: There is the [Presentation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Presentation_API), maybe it would suit better your needs? However it should be noted (even though OP didn't ask for this browser) that Chrome do not allow programmatically moving/opening a new window on an other monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following diagram, in the multi-monitor/screen environment, the element position in second screen is the start of (1920,0) (suppose the screen resolution is 1920*1080).

```
// X,Y                  X,Y                    S = Screen, W = Window
// 0,0  ----------   1920,0  ----------
//     |          |         |  ---     |
//     |          |         | | W |    |
//     |        S |         |  ---   S |
```

So, we could get the parent window position first, then compare with the screen width and detect whether it is located on the first or second screen, Then, when we open the popup window, we could set the window left property and open it in another screen.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenWindow() {
    PopupCenter("https://www.google.com/", "Google", 900, 500, null);
}
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h, opts) {
   var _innerOpts = '';
   if(opts !== null && typeof opts === 'object' ){
       for (var p in opts ) {
           if (opts.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
               _innerOpts += p + '=' + opts[p] + ',';
           }
       }
    }
    //get the screen width and height.
    var screenwidth = window.screen.width;
    var screenheight = window.screen.height;
    console.log("screen width: " + screenwidth);
    console.log("screen height: " + screenheight);

   //get current window position. For Firefox, use ["window.screenX"](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_screenx.asp) and ["window.screenY"](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_screenx.asp) 
   // Fixes dual-screen position, Most browsers, Firefox
   var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
   var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
   console.log('dualScreenLeft' + dualScreenLeft); 
    console.log('dualScreenTop' + dualScreenTop); 

   //get current window width and height
   var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
   var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;
   console.log('current window wigth:' + width); 
   console.log('current window height:' + height); 

   var left = 0;
   var top = 0;
   console.log('calculated left ' + left); 
   console.log('calcualted top ' + top); 
    //if parent window located in the second screen. set the popup window left property: from 0 to 1920 (the first screen width)
    if (dualScreenLeft >= 1920) {
        left = 0;
    }
    else {
        //
        left = 1920;
    }
   var newWindow = window.open(url, title, _innerOpts + ' width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
    // Puts focus on the newWindow
    if (window.focus()) {
       newWindow.focus();
   }
};
</script>
<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="OpenWindow();" />
```