# Is there a way using JavaScript to open a new window in another monitor?

Tags: javascript, window, multiple-monitors

I have some web-based reports that open in a new browser window. Users have asked if they can pick which monitor a report opens in. Is there a way in JavaScript to target a 2nd (or 3rd) monitor for a new browser window?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363474/window-open-on-a-multi-monitor-dual-monitor-system-where-does-window-pop-up