# Popup Onclick form

Tags: php, javascript

Hi having a bit of a problem what I'm trying to do is once a user has clicked a **button**
the **button** should show a popup of a **form** so they might enter a value which is a **date** so it may be  used for future uses and the popup has a submit button so process the action
with this code:

```
     if (isset($_POST['unenroll'])){
        $sql1="Update tbl_enroll SET status='unEnrolled' , counter='0' 
              period='$pweek";
                    $pow = mysql_query($sql1) or die (mysql_error());
                    }
```

I am having a problem on how to create the popup so far i have this:

```
     onclick="window.open‘unenroll.php’,‘Unenroll’,
   ‘menubar=no,width=200,height=100,toolbar=no’)"
```

So far it just not creating the popup form. would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)

Comment: the window.open above is missing the open bracket - window.open('unenroll.php'...

Comment: @BhuvanRikka i will check that out, looking at it fixed its a little bit ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong quotes and also a bracket is missing. Try this here:

```
onclick="window.open('unenroll.php', 'Unenroll', 'menubar=no,width=200,height=100,toolbar=no')"
```

Note that this must be in one line and also care about the php variable `$pweek` If that comes from the client you open a blind sql injection hole.

In your SQL statement is also a quote and a comma missing:

```
$sql1="Update tbl_enroll SET status='unEnrolled', counter='0', period='$pweek'";
```

Comment: Thank you that helped, but wasn't expecting the output it looks ugly. =( need to disable the maximize button and center it is that possible?

Comment: @Tony For putting the popup in the middle of the screen read please: [Center a popup window on screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen). To disable the maximize is so far I know not possible.

Comment: Do you think there is better way in doing this because i was imagining  this looking like a Onclick=Confirm return, else i just have to make due with this.

Comment: I don't know what your `unenroll.php` is displaying, but of cause you could use a confirm box too. With `onclick="if(confirm('msg')) doSomething();"` you can do what you want.

Comment: My bad for not telling, I think i can't do that because the onclick it would show a form that can submit the entered data on that **form**.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can slove that problem. Maybe with the [target attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp) on the form, but this is not standard conform.

Answer (score 0):

the popup wont be a better option because its either blocked by browse or by users so the i think better approach will be make a div and show the div on click

html

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#demo").hide();
     $(document).live("click",function(){
          $("#demo").show();

      }) 
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, First time to use Jquery how should i insert that? inside of `<style>` at header?

Comment: @Tony include this in the bottom of the  page just before the </body>

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick should be like this

```
onclick="window.open('unenroll.php', 'Unenroll', 'menubar=no,resizable=no,width=200,height=100,toolbar=no,left='+((screen.width/2)-50)+',top='+((screen.height/2)-50))"
```

resizable=no will disable maximize button.

```
left = (screen.width/2)-50;
top = (screen.height/2)-50;
```

should center the popup in your case...