# Pop up window needs centering on screen

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

I have this table down the side of this form I'm working on that has hyperlink buttons. The button are for FAQ. What I'm trying to do is when the hyperlink button is clicked I want a small text box, empty browser, whatever may be the simplest approach. I have the page launching with my text in it but it opens up on the left hand corner of my screen.

Here's what I have for code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBttnPsswrdReset" runat="server" OnClientClick="openPopUp()">Password Reset Info</asp:LinkButton><br />

<%--function to open pop up window for password reset hyperlink button --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPopUp() {
        myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=250,height=250')
        myWindow.document.write("<p>Please contact the operator to reset yopur password after IT department business hours</p>")
        myWindow
        myWindow.focus()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: does the following link answer your question? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen

Comment: Ive tried those and they weren't working for me

Comment: well im sorry they worked but they pretty much got the same point im at at which is launching the creen but not really centering it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used Ajax comboBox.....worked nicely

Answer (score 1):

your question look similar to previous question such as the following link.

[Center a popup window on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen)

accepted answer copied and pasted below

try this:

```
function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no,      menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you something like [AlertifyJs](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/0.4.0rc1/), which is much nicer in every aspect, than a nasty Popup.