# Center a JavaScript window in all modern browsers without extra functions

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a problem in getting a JavaScript window centred in Google Chrome, I have found a solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen) but it's creating a new JavaScript function that calls the `Window.Open`.

How to do get it centred in all browsers using `Window.Open` Only?

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgNew"  onclientclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank','channelmode =1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=0,width=400,height:300');" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed Width and height Try:

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+400+', height='+300+', top='+ Number((screen.height/2)-(300/2)) +', left='+  Number((screen.width/2)-(400/2)) );return false;
```

On ImageButton with a disabled Postback:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgNew" onclientclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+400+', height='+300+', top='+ Number((screen.height/2)-(300/2)) +', left='+  Number((screen.width/2)-(400/2)) );return false;" PostBackUrl="javascript:void(0);" />
```

Comment: To force Chrome to open a full screen window use:


`window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+screen.width+', height='+screen.height+', top='+ Number(0) +', left='+  Number(0) );`