# Open a frame in center of current window

Tags: javascript, html

How can I open a frame in the center of the current window?

The JS is simple:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", "activate-frame", "height=600,width=800,centerscreen,chrome=yes");
```

However the "centerscreen" attribute is not actually opening the frame in the center of the screen.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecm9bpox/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate the screen width and height before placing the window on the screen.

Something like this:

```
function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
  var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
  return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
} 

popupwindow('http://google.com','Test Frame',600, 800)
```

[As answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen), in a similar Stack Overflow post.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear, but according to the Mozilla documentation it may only work with chrome scripts.

> var win = window.open("chrome://myextension/content/about.xul", 
>     "aboutMyExtension", "chrome,centerscreen");

The first parameter to window.open is the **URI of the XUL file** that describes the window and its contents.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code

Answer (score 1):

To show new popup window at the **center of the parent one** use its properties `screenTop`, `screenLeft`, `innerHeight` and `innerWidth` to calculate the center point and then pass it to `window.open`.

Here's working example:

```
var opts = {
    url: "https://example.com",  // Popup URL here
    width: 600,                  // Popup width here
    height: 600                  // Popup height here
};
var parentCenter = {
    top: window.screenTop + (window.innerHeight / 2),
    left: window.screenLeft + (window.innerWidth / 2)
};
var offset = {
    top: parentCenter.top - (opts.height / 2),
    left: parentCenter.left - (opts.width / 2)
};  
window.open(opts.url, 'mywindow', 'width=' + opts.width + ',height=' + opts.height + ',top='+offset.top+',left=' + offset.left);
```