# Can't get centered popup to work

Tags: javascript, popup

This is driving me nuts. I'm a copy/paste kind of guy(!) so please be gentle.

Previously, I've used [this solution](http://www.xtf.dk/2011/08/center-new-popup-window-even-on.html) ([Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen)) to make a centered popup which has worked perfectly (on in internal CMS site) but for some reason, I can't get it to work on a new site (not on the CMS).

I know I'm missing something but I just can't see what it is!!

HTML:

```
<a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com" onclick="PopupCenter(this.href,'myWindow','550','550');return false" target="_blank">Center Popup</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {  
    // Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox  
    var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;  
    var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;  

    width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;  
    height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;  

    var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;  
    var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;  
    var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);  

    // Puts focus on the newWindow  
    if (window.focus) {  
        newWindow.focus();  
    }  
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kungfauxn00b/nxg532p8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pop Up</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com" onclick="PopupCenter(this.href,'myWindow','550','550');return false" target="_blank">Center Popup</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Huh!? Is it!!? Any ideas why it's not working for me then? This is the link I've got in the <head> section:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/centeredpopup.js"></script>

Comment: No this has nothing to do with your function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h)

Comment: You should have an html file like popup.html  and   a JS file as popup.js that contains your function
Then <script src="popup.js"></script>  in your popup.html to tell your html where to find your function

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I've got that. I've even tried adding the JS in <script> tags in the HTML page.

Comment: It also works if you insert the function code inside a script tags in the head of the HTML