# On click open image in center of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i tried to make my gallery more better. I want when user click on element to open image in the middle of the screen. I'm sure that there is efficient way to do this with adding class or something.
What should i do ?

**HTML**

```
    <ul class="gallery">
        <li>
            <img  src="img/1.png" />
            <div class="caption" onclick="view('1.png')">
                <div class="blur"></div>
                <div class="caption-text">
                    <h1>+</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img  src="img/2.png" onClick="view('2.png');">
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="blur"></div>
                <div class="caption-text">
                    <h1>+</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function view(imgsrc) {
      viewwin = window.open(imgsrc,'viewwin', 'width=600,height=300'); 
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't use a plugin such as [`fancybox`](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)?

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle (or relevant) demo link.

Comment: Try this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen

Comment: This webpage - http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp has a simple tutorial explaining how to make one with CSS and JavaScript and how it works. Or use a ready made plugin from the internet.

Comment: JSFiddle example of the code stated in the question at https://jsfiddle.net/wqcqg0t2/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have exactly what you are looking for.

You can look for some css and an example [here](http://codepen.io/supah/pen/ZWGJeR)

This is where the magic happens:

```
popup = {
 init: function(){
  $('li').click(function(){
    popup.open($(this));
  });

$(document).on('click', '.popup img', function(){
  return false;
}).on('click', '.popup', function(){
  popup.close();
})
},
open: function($li) {
$('.gallery').addClass('pop');
$popup = $('<div class="popup" />').appendTo($('body'));
$fig = $li.clone().appendTo($('.popup'));
$bg = $('<div class="bg" />').appendTo($('.popup'));
$close = $('<div class="close"><svg><use xlink:href="#close"></use></svg></div>').appendTo($fig);
$shadow = $('<div class="shadow" />').appendTo($fig);
src = $('img', $fig).attr('src');
$shadow.css({backgroundImage: 'url(' + src + ')'});
$bg.css({backgroundImage: 'url(' + src + ')'});
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.popup').addClass('pop');
}, 10);
},
close: function(){
$('.gallery, .popup').removeClass('pop');
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.popup').remove()
}, 100);
}
}

popup.init()
```

This should cover the popup logic.

For the centering issue you should check out the link above and look at the css documentation

**Fabio Ottaviani**'s work, nicely done.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try out imgZoom, a jQuery plugin to easily integrate zooming function to your current images: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgzoom/