# Javascript window.open function attributes

Tags: javascript

How to open a new window within  the parent window such that the content of the parent window is visible? Are there any attributes that can be supplied to window.open("URL","_parent) javascript function?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: What do you mean "visible"? Are you trying to open a translucent window? A window that is smaller? A secret window that hides at the back running a bitcoin mining script that you hope the visitor won't notice for ages? Have you tried [reading the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to see what paramaters the function accepts?

Comment: Better refference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: I meant the child window should not replace the parent window. It must be dockable within the parent window.

Comment: No. You need an iframe, not a window.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [Center a popup window on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen) for popup window. No need for new window. Use popup window of javascript.

This http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html may also help you.