# Window.open() not lining up all the way to the left of current window

Tags: javascript, html, css

When using `window.open()` to open a popup window, the popup window is opening slightly to the right of the window I am opening the popup from. It lines up directly left with the `body` when margin is not removed but I have set my css like so:

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

I have also tried to set `left=0px` in my `window.open` function.

Here's my JS code:

```
var windowSize = "width=" + window.innerWidth + ",height=" + window.innerHeight + ",left=0px";
window.open('http://www.google.com/', 'popup', windowSize);
```

Anyone know why this is occuring? Is there any solution to alleviate this problem?

Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jg9y89g0/3/).

**UPDATE**

Here you can see that you can see some red to the left of the popup:

[image]

Comment: So where do you want it now?Right or left?

Comment: I want it to line up all the way to the left of the window I am opening it from but there seems to be a slight "margin".

Comment: When you set `left=0px` it aligns the window 0px offset from the left. Your fiddle shows no margin on my end.

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine. It is aligned to the left with no margin.

Comment: That's strange. It's not working for me. Please see my update.

Comment: Perhaps it has to do how Chrome treats focus and popups? This user seems to have perhaps found a [possible workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen)?

Comment: I using 3 screens, same fiddle works fine in 2 screens, but popup aligned to the right on 3rd. I using Windows 7 & chrome.

Comment: I'm using dual monitors and on both screens there is a slight "margin". I'm using windows 10 and have tested on chrome and firefox.