# Cannot position windows with window.open()

Tags: javascript, window.open

My objective is to position a new window opened with the `window.open()` method in the bottom righthand corner of the screen, but setting `right=0` and `bottom=0` does not work.

Changing `width` and `height` makes a difference, but changing `top`, `bottom`, `right` or `left` still results in the window opening in the top lefthand corner.

Why is this and how would one position the window in the lower right hand corner?

```
window.open('https://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes, height=250,width=550, right=0, bottom=0, scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
```

Comment: Have you been able to test my answer? Did you solve the problem you are having?

Comment: Not the solution but no spaces allowed in the `windowFeatures` parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the top and left to the inner height and width minus the height and width of your new window.

```
<script>
    function OpenMe(){
    var height = 250;
    var width = 550;
    var top = window.innerHeight-height;
    var left = window.innerWidth-width;
    window.open(
        'https://google.com', 
        '_blank', 
        'location=yes,height='+height+',width='+width+',top='+top+',left='+left+',scrollbars=yes,status=yes'
    );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This solution is not working. That calculated 'left' parameter does not position the window correctly.

Here is the JavaScript code that does the job:
const left = screen.availLeft + (screen.availWidth - width) / 2;

Answer (score 4):

If opened from a browser window on the main monitor, positioning works just fine.  If opened from a browser window on a different monitor then positioning fails. I tested this in Chrome.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33187536)

Comment: you can find dual monitor fix here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16861050/4896948