# How do I open a window on a different screen?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an IE7 app that needs to open a popup window onto a second screen. I'm fudging this at the moment by extending the desktop and explicitly opening the window at an offset that makes it appear over on the other one. However this seems like a hack and I'd like to be able to explicitly set the window screen when I call window.open(). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What if the user only has 1 screen?

Comment: This seems not possible at all. I had an idea involving `window.screenX` and `moveTo` but they do not seem to give reliable results. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140462/testing-for-multiple-screens-with-javascript

Comment: In our case the user has 2 screens. The idea is the operator processes claims. The webapp is on one screen and a scanned document is on the other. Unfortunately as the developer I don't have two screens so it would be nice to have explicit browser level api so it would fall back onto the mainscreen. But it doesn't sound like there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. I did some testing and the pop-up windows seemed to be restricted to the monitor "with focus".

#### Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/25W29](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/25W29/)