# Javascript: Count number of screen

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

We are developing a web application that will use 4 screens. Is there a way to count the number of screens?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140462/testing-for-multiple-screens-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

This may help

Assuming rectangular arrangement of screen and all screen has same height and width.

```
 /// total window width divided by single screen width

var h_screens = Math.round(window.outerWidth / window.screen.availWidth);

 /// total window height divided by single screen height
var v_creens = Math.round(window.outerHeight / window.screen.availHeight);
var total_screens = h_screens * v_creens;
```

- ▆ ▆
     ▆ ▆

  4 = 2* 2;

Comment: This doesn't work on Google Chrome. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234132